# Querying a mySQL Database with php. How to Set WHERE to a php var

Tags: php, mysql

So I am working on search engine for mySQL database on a website. And I Want the user to be able to select how they are going to be searching. Like so...

```
$searchBy=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['recordType']); 
$searchText=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['searchText']); 

$getRecordsSQL = "SELECT * FROM weighs WHERE ID='$searchText'"; 
$recordsQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$getRecordsSQL);
```

The above code works, but only for searching by ID. How would I get it to look something like this..

```
$searchBy=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['recordType']); 
$searchText=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['searchText']); 

$getRecordsSQL = "SELECT * FROM weighs WHERE '$searchBy'='$searchText'"; 
$recordsQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$getRecordsSQL);
```

That code does not work, but you get the point. Is there a way to format that query so the user can pick the column they would like to look at, Aka WHERE?

Comment: You really should not be using escape strings.  Use a prepared statement with a parameter for  searchText and use a whitelist for searchBy.    Once you have that in place, use backticks, not quotes for column names.

Comment: If you want to make a PHP variable be a column, it must be in ticks. And you should also whitelist it before using it in a query!

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: `real_escape_string` is for *user data only* and not column names.

Answer (score -2):

```
 //this must be in selection for search

  <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="searchText">
   <select id="searchBy">
    <option value="table name">table name</option>
    <option value="table name 1">table name 1</option>
    <option value="table name 2">table name 2</option>
    <option value="table name 3">table name 3</option>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </select>
 </form>







<script>
//after you have to send value from from select to php with ajax or jquery
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").on("click" ,function(){
     var searchBy= $("#searchBy").val();
     var searchText=  $("#searchText").val();

    $.ajax({
       url: 'link_page_to_php_sql.php', 
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: {searchBy: searchBy, searchText : searchText},
        type: 'POST',
         success: function (response) {
            //some cod here if you wont after succes 
         }
     });
   });
   });
```

```
  <?php
     //and this for sql  link_page_to_php_sql.php
   if (isset($_POST['searchBy'])){
    $searchBy = $_POST['searchBy'];
    $searchText= $_POST['searchText'];
  }
     $getRecordsSQL = "SELECT * FROM weighs WHERE '$searchBy'='$searchText'"; 
     $recordsQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$getRecordsSQL); 
  ?>
```

Comment: Your version is worse than the OP's. At least he was using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: You can't have `<input>` inside `<select>`.

Comment: what do you wont to make  all form search complete? :))

Comment: The column name shouldn't be in quotes, it should be in backticks.

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong in the question, and how you're fixing the problem. Don't just post code without explanation.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you write better English?

Comment: are you sure ? tray to see if is working

Comment: What's the difference between your `$getRecordsSQL` and the one in the question?